# Dynamically set the WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Issuer and Realm property

Tags: asp.net, wif

I want to avoid having the  node in web.config and hence set the Issuer and Realm dynamically in the OnAuthenticateRequest event. But i get the error "system.argumentexception: id0006: the input string parameter is either null or empty. parameter name: issuer"

I get this error before the OnAuthenticateRequest event is raised. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you need to provide the configuration before you start authenticating.  This can be done in the web.config.  You can also tap into the event  FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated +=
                FederatedAuthenticationOnFederationConfigurationCreated;

To start providing your own configuration.